# Getting list of system printer names very slow in windows

Tags: windows, qt, printing

I need to create a very custom widget for printing. It has to be multi-platform as well. For consistency, the widget should be similar looking in windows as in linux or mac... After studying the Qt code, which uses the Windows print dialog, I gave up trying to subclass Qt print dialog, and made my own widget.

So, now I am on step 1: populate the list of printers on the system. I added the following code, to be called on each "show()" - just in case printers on the system change during program execution - and it works, but it is extremely slow:

I create a map of index/printer, and add the default printer as index -1, to tell the widget which one it is.

```
QMap<int, QString> PrintController::getListOfSystemPrinters()
{
    QMap<int, QString> printerNames;

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
#ifdef NOT_QT_4   // I tried to use "availablePrinterNames" thinking it will be faster but it actually seems slower
    QPrinter currentPrinter;
    QString printerName = currentPrinter.printerName();

    QStringList printerNameList = QPrinterInfo::availablePrinterNames();

    int index = 0;
    foreach(QString printerName1, printerNameList)
    {
        printerNames.insert(index, printerName1);
        if(printerName == printerName1)
            printerNames.insert(-1, printerName1);
        ++index;
    }
#else
    QPrinter currentPrinter;
    QString printerName = currentPrinter.printerName();

    QList<QPrinterInfo> printers = QPrinterInfo::availablePrinters();

    int index = 0;
    foreach(QPrinterInfo printerInfo, printers)
    {
        QString printerName1 = printerInfo.printerName();
        printerNames.insert(index, printerName1);
        if(printerName == printerName1)
            printerNames.insert(-1, printerName1);
        ++index;
    }
#endif
#elif defined Q_OS_UNIX

#endif

    return printerNames;
}
```

This is the slowest piece of code I have ! I don't see another way to get all printer names... But I must be doing something wrong !
The Qt 5 version is slightly slower than the Qt 4 version... Either way, they are both slow....
The call to create a `QPrinterInfo` is slow.
So... are there alternatives ?

How can I get the list of printer names in Windows ?

Note this must work in Qt 4.7-5.x

Comment: `availablePrinterNames()` here (Qt 5.6.1 on windows) takes about `9-13 msecs` to finish. while `availablePrinters()` takes about `110-150 msecs`. not that long time, I really think it is something that has to do with your current setup, maybe your printers' drivers

Comment: @Mike - I read online that the slowness may have to do with having network printers... It is possible that I even have installed network printers that don't really resolve to a real printer... I did not time it just watching it seems that using availablePrinterNames takes a little bit longer. But it may have to be because of the printers themselves... idk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get printer list asynchronously:

```
class Class : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_SIGNAL void hasPrinters(const QList<QPrinterInfo> &);
   Q_SIGNAL void hasPrinterNames(const QStringList &);

   /// This method is thread-safe
   void getPrinters() {
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,3,0)
         emit hasPrinterNames(QPrinterInfo::availablePrinterNames());
#else
         emit hasPrinters(QPrinterInfo::availablePrinters());
#endif
   }
   void test() {
      QtConcurrent::run(this, &Class::getPrinters);
   }
};
```

The above compiles on Qt 4.7 & up, using either C++98 or C++11.

Connect to the `hasPrinterNames`/`hasPrinters` signal to be notified when the printer list is available, then populate your dialog.

You might be lucky and `availablePrinterNames`/`availablePrinters` will be thread-safe. I haven't checked if it is.

On Qt 5.3 and newer, only create the `QPrinterInfo` for a given printer once your user has selected it, and you might want to create it concurrently as well.